# Query Parameters with Strapi

Tags: node.js, api, strapi

I'm using Strapi with MongoDB Atlas and I have two collection types:

```
1. Illustrations
2. Categories
```

I have different illustrations belonging to different categories

The relationship is one-to-many which means that Illustrations has and belongs to many Categories

When I go to http://localhost:1337/illustrations I get all the illustrations regardless their categories

So after looking at the documentation I don't find any query params so that I get only illustrations of a specific category

NB: I'm not using GraphQL

Comment: can you paste a subset of the response from http://localhost:1337/illustrations? It will be possible to answer your query very confidentally. 

But in general you should be able to query for illustrations with a particular category using a query like http://localhost:1337/illustrations?categories.name=nature